# Flask/Axios No se envían o reciben los parámetros en petición POST

Tags: python, vue.js, flask, axios

Tengo un que realizar un envió de dos números a través de método POST, a traves de VUE y axios, para poder realizar unas peticiones a base de datos, esto último a través de Flask.

El metodo inicial de flask es el siguiente:

```
@mod.route('/flujo',methods=('GET','POST'))
def flujo():
    print(request.args)
    param1= request.args.get("flujo")
    param2= request.args.get("orden_siguiente")
    print(param1)
    print(param2)
    return 'ok'
```

Además de ello tengo en el fichero inicial de la app de Flask lo siguiente:

```
app=Flask(__name__)
app.config['JSON_SORT_KEYS'] = False
cors = CORS(app, resources={r"/api/*": {"origins": "*"}})
```

Y para realizar la petición POST tengo el siguiente código:

```
cargaInicial: function () {
        const params = new URLSearchParams()
        flujo = '1'
        orden_siguiente = '2'
        params.append('flujo', flujo)
        if (orden_siguiente != null){
           params.append('orden_siguiente',orden_siguiente)
        }else{
           params.append('orden_siguiente','1')
        }

        instance.post("/plantillas/flujo",params).then(response => {
          console.log(response)
        })
```

El problema es que no están llegando los parametros, ya que sacando el log de "request.args" en el servicio Flask tengo esta respuesta:

"ImmutableMultiDict([])"

Mientras que si hago la petición directa por postman me devuelve bien los parametros pasados:

Petición postman:

http://localhost:5000/plantillas/flujo?flujo=7&orden_siguiente=2

Log:

ImmutableMultiDict([('flujo', '7'), ('orden_siguiente', '2')])

Luego me puse a probar con el metodo GET, y con este si que me recupera los parámetros sin problema

¿Alguien sabe que estoy haciendo mal o que me falta para que funcione con el método POST?

Comment: En Flask, en `request.args` tienes los parámetros recibidos a través de la _query_ en la URL. Estos parámetros son los que estás enviando en la URL de ejemplo que muestras para Postman, y es también donde AJAX pone los datos en una petición GET. En las peticiones POST, en cambio, no se envía nada en la URL y por eso `request.args` está vacío. En ese caso debes usar `request.get_json()`

Comment: Probé con esa forma, pero no retornaba nada, al final lo que he hecho ha sido tirar de `request.form["nombre_var"]` y desde VUE enviarlo como FormData, y asi ya si que lo ha cogido

Comment: Tenías mal entonces el "frontend". Desde javascript tienes que enviar un json y asegurarte de que la cabecera `Content-type:` tiene el valor `application/json`. Pensé que Axios (que desconozco) lo haría automáticamente.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Al final como solución implementé otra clase para almacenar los datos, FormData, como muestro a continuación:

```
cargaInicial: function () {
        const params = new FormData
        id_flujo = '1'
        orden_siguiente = '2'
        params.append('flujo', id_flujo)
        if (orden_siguiente != null){
           params.append('orden_siguiente',orden_siguiente)
        }else{
            params.append('orden_siguiente','1')
        }
        console.log('sigue mas, ' + params)

        instance.post("/plantillas/flujo",params).then(response => {
          console.log(response)
        })}
```

Y a la hora de la recepción en el back lo trato de la siguiente manera:

```
def flujo(): 

    param1= request.form["flujo"]
    param2= request.form["orden_siguiente"]

    return 'ok'
```